# backup and restore error

Tags: backup

I am trying to take full farm backup using PowerShell and from CA in 2019 SharePoint. but I am getting error

```
Object WSS_Content failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see 
the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 

SqlException: Cannot open backup device '\\servername\spbackup\spbr0000\00000089.bak'.
Operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.). 
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The permission has been given to SQL server account and also to the farm account and also shared the folder to SQL server account and farm account it creates other .bak but fails only some of the .bak files.

**What is the solution for this error?**

Comment: Do you have enough space on that drive to hold the backup that you are trying to create?

Comment: Thanks Josh issue was the SharePoint servers were in a secured network and the SQL credentials doesn't have access to the secured network once the firewall was correctly configured everything works fine.